# Django - long running tasks

Tags: django, celery, django-celery, django-channels

Im looking for and advice for long running tasks in Django. This is my use case:
I have an eshop order with over 200 products (rows). When I click on "process" Django runs a function (which consists of multiple smaller functions) to process data. This may take some time but while this task is running, I want to let a user know about the process status. During that time the order is "locked".
My current theory is to use combination of Django Celery (or its equivalent) and Django channels. Once the task is done, Channels will push a message via websocket to the frontend and JS will change objects (button, status, texts...). When task starts, a function updates the status in DB. After task is finished, status in DB is updated again.
Because the app is not SPA and im using standard Django views and templates, this solution would not work in case the task will end during page refresh. So after the page is loaded again, task is not running, WS wont send any update but at the same time DB query has old status. Example:
When process starts I save status as "running". When Celery task is finished, status in DB is changed to "done". During page reload (after hitting "process" button) the task has finished, DB is updated BUT View DB query got old value of the status. The result after page reload is that Vie and template have status "running" but in DB is already "done" - bad timing.
How to solve this issue? How to overcome this situation? I dont want to manually delay task execution.

Comment: Can you highlight what exactly is your question about?

Comment: The problem is in notifying a user about the status of order. When the task task longer than view's response (page reload), everything is fine. The problem task place when the task takes the exact same time as page reload. Reason: task marked as done in DB, but the view queried DB just before celery saved the value. So user sees the order as in progress while in reality in DB is already done. - no further notification is then triggered.

Comment: OK, when you use Celery — you should not rely on timing, as the task execution is unknown, I guess this is totally clear for you.

So you want some suggestions how exactly you can implement some solution to wait properly for the task completion?

Comment: thats right. Because the solution I currently have suffers from mentioned issue. It works ... but... only when when task task longer than view render.

Comment: OK, I've provided below an answer with some brief description how I'd resolve this issue in the simplest (in my opinion) way. Please let me know in comment, if it's enough for you to move forward.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In case the function execution time is under 30 seconds — I'd suggest to not bother with Celery and just put the whole thing into request.

In case you actually must go with Celery, you can implement this in a next way:

1. Create some Django model to track tasks. It will have some ID field (value of which you'll return immediately after the request is finished and it will be used by some JS code). Also you could put all input data for the Celery task there, and there will be `status` field.
2. In JS code, in case you don't *actually* need it, I'd not bother with WebSockets — old good polling should be enough for implementation of periodical checks of the state of your task.
3. JS code should send request to some endpoint, which will return the `state` field value for the task.

In addition to `state` field, you also can return some insights on the actual progress (if the logic allows it).